# Free Pascal String Return from Function Encoding Issue?

Tags: pascal

When iterating through a singly linked list with characters to return the resulting string (char-array indexed from 1) I always get the following output in my terminal:

```
A☺♦H A☺
```

Is this an encoding issue? It is completely independent of the characters I read in. Following is the function  and then the whole program

```
  FUNCTION StringOf(cl: CharListPtr): STRING;
  VAR
    n: CharNodePtr;
    max, i: INTEGER;
    s, StringOf: STRING;
  BEGIN
    n := cl;
    max := 255;
    i := 1;
    s := '';
    WHILE (n<>NIL) AND (i<=max) DO BEGIN
      //Write(n^.ch);
      s[i] := n^.ch;
      //Write(s[i]);
      i := i + 1;
      n := n^.next;
    END;
    s[0] := chr(i);
    //Write(s[0]);
    //Write(chr(4));
    StringOf := s;
  END;
```

In context:

```
PROGRAM SLLStrings;
TYPE
  CharNodePtr = ^CharNode;
  CharNode = RECORD
    next: CharNodePtr;
    ch: CHAR;
  END; (* ListNode *)
  CharListPtr = CharNodePtr;

  PROCEDURE Append(VAR l: CharListPtr; n: CharNodePtr);
  VAR
    last: CharNodePtr;
  BEGIN
    IF l = NIL THEN BEGIN
      l := n;
    END
    ELSE BEGIN
      last := l;
      WHILE last^.next <> NIL DO BEGIN
        last := last^.next;
      END;
      last^.next := n;
    END;
  END;

  PROCEDURE Prepend(VAR l: CharListPtr; n: CharNodePtr);
  BEGIN
    n^.next := l;
    l := n;
  END;

  PROCEDURE DisposeCharList(VAR cl: CharListPtr);
  VAR
    succ: CharNodePtr;
  BEGIN
    WHILE (cl<>NIL) DO BEGIN
      succ := cl^.next;
      Dispose(cl);
      cl := succ;
    END;
  END;

  FUNCTION StringOf(cl: CharListPtr): STRING;
  VAR
    n: CharNodePtr;
    max, i: INTEGER;
    s, StringOf: STRING;
  BEGIN
    n := cl;
    max := 255;
    i := 1;
    s := '';
    WHILE (n<>NIL) AND (i<=max) DO BEGIN
      //Write(n^.ch);
      s[i] := n^.ch;
      //Write(s[i]);
      i := i + 1;
      n := n^.next;
    END;
    s[0] := chr(i);
    //Write(s[0]);
    //Write(chr(4));
    StringOf := s;
  END;

  FUNCTION NewCharList: CharListPtr;
  VAR
    l: CharNodePtr;
    NewCharList: CharListPtr;
  BEGIN (* NewCharList *)
    l := NIL;
    NewCharList := l;
  END; (* NewCharList *)

  FUNCTION NewNode(_ch: CHAR): CharNodePtr;
  VAR
    n: CharNodePtr;
  BEGIN
    New(n);
    n^.next := NIL;
    n^.ch := _ch;
    NewNode := n;
  END;

VAR
  l: CharListPtr;
  ch: CHAR;
  i: INTEGER;
  s: STRING;
BEGIN
  (* Test Case Empty List *)
  l := NewCharList();
  Append(l, NewNode('a'));
  Append(l, NewNode('b'));
  Append(l, NewNode('c'));
  s := StringOf(l);
  WriteLn(s);
  
END.
```

Output is always

A☺♦H A☺

Comment: When I learned Pascal, one did _not_ declare a variable within a function that held the same name as the function - the function header effectively declared the return "variable".

Comment: That was the problem! I must have misunderstood how it works, thanks for clearing it up. It works when I don't declare the function name as a separate variable, which makes sense too.

Comment: You don't specify which compiler and -version you use, but in some writing s[x] before setting the length of S to be equal or larger than x, might be illegal.

Comment: Just a style comment: upper-casing Pascal keywords has pretty much gone the way of the fax machine by now.